# Java - Replacing word with assigned numbers

Tags: replace, numbers, alphabet

I would like to make this code shorter and cleaner.
This code works properly, but It is to long for me:

```
            String givenWord = "help";

           
            String partA = givenWord.replace("a", "1");
            String partB = partA.replace("b", "2");
            String partC = partB.replace("c", "10");
            String partD = partC.replace("d", "11");
            String partE = partD.replace("e", "12");
            String partF = partE.replace("f", "20");
            String partG = partF.replace("g", "21");
            String partH = partG.replace("h", "22");
            String partI = partH.replace("i", "100");
            String partJ = partI.replace("j", "101");
            String partK = partJ.replace("k", "102");
            String partL = partK.replace("l", "110");
            String partM = partL.replace("m", "111");
            String partN = partM.replace("n", "112");
            String partO = partN.replace("o", "120");
            String partQ = partO.replace("q", "121");
            String partP = partQ.replace("p", "122");
            String partR = partP.replace("r", "200");
            String partS = partR.replace("s", "201");
            String partT = partS.replace("t", "202");
            String partU = partT.replace("u", "210");
            String partV = partU.replace("v", "211");
            String partW = partV.replace("w", "212");
            String partX = partW.replace("x", "220");
            String partY = partX.replace("y", "221");
            String partZ = partY.replace("z", "222");

            System.out.println(partZ);
```

I need to replace all letters in the given word like that:
The output is 2220110122.

I have tried to use 'for loops' and other methods, but they didn't work well.
I am a beginner, that's why I am asking here :)